# c# unity divide configuration into multiple files

Tags: c#, xml, configuration, unity-container

is it possible in unity IoC to divide configuration file into multiple ones? I mean in the basic file I would just somehow include the other configuration files, just to keep code clean a little. Is here such a functionality in unity? Because now, I'm having just 1 big app.config where all the registration happens and it is becoming very unreadable. Thanks in advance

Comment: how big exactly is  app.config  ?

Comment: do you want to split unity alone to separate config file or to have parts of unity in different files

Comment: So far it is not that big at all, but the application is not configured yet. I'm doing lot of dynamic configuration via unity and by the time it might have grown up to 2000-3000 lines and it would be really great to have it structured even if it was less then that.

Comment: I want to have parts of unity in different files.

Comment: I said it before and I'll say it again, your config file should have as little DI configuration as possible. Only things that must be able to change after deployment (and don't need the work of a developer anyway) should be made configurable. The rest of the configuration should be placed in code.

Comment: and anyway is here the way to do so? Because I have many things which need to be configured and don't need a hand of developer, so I'd like to keep xml clear at least a little.